# Consequences of applying a non-injective function to both parts of an (original) equation $f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I apply non-injective function to both parts of an (original) equation $f(x)=g(x)$, getting thus a resulting equation, then is this always true about the resulting equation:

1. all roots of the original equation are among the roots of the resulting equation (so that I do not miss/lose any roots)
2. Resulting equation may have roots which are not roots of the original equation (alien/extraneous  roots), so I need to check all roots of the resulting equation (substituting them into the original equation and checking if they would produce $0=0$).
3. When I apply my non-injective function $d(x)$, I must ensure that domain D(d(x)) includes union of Ranges of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, otherwise application of d(x) is incorrect. If domain of $d(x)$ is R (all real numbers) - I don't have to care about this.

So in any case lost roots are not possible, but extraneous roots are quite possible.

Is all this correct and are there any other interesting implications/consequences (of applying non-injective function to both parts of an equation)?

P.S. A post concerning applying injective function to an equation is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283013/applying-any-injective-function-dx-to-the-equation-fx-gx-is-always-an-equi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems mostly correct.  I'd quibble with the wording on point 3.  If the domain of $d$ doesn't include the ranges of $f$ and $g$, then it's not "incorrect" to apply $d$.  Rather, there will be places where the expressions are undefined.  And if the domain of $d$ is all real numbers, you're still caring about "this."  It's just that "this" is easily taken care of.

On point 2, what if $d(x) =2$ for all $x$?  Then every number is a solution to the equation.  So you might have uncountably many extraneous roots to check, which would take you quite a while.